# System.BadImageFormatException Error on VS Code Startup

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I am in the process of getting everything I need to start learning C# and I've run into an issue. I am trying to use VS code as my editor but the IntelliSense isn't working. I think it's because OmniSharp cannot start up. When it tries to it run into this error:  `System.BadImageFormatException`. I'm doing this on a brand new project, literally, all I've done is run the command `dotnet new console` and then OmniSharp cannot open. If it's relevant I'm using Mac and have the latest updates installed. Any idea what's causing this error and how I can fix it?

Thank you for any and all help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after some trial and error I realized I was using the wrong sdk. So, if anyone else is having this problem make sure you have the right one! I ended up needing the Arm one and not the normal one.